# use of keycde in the jquery plugin without passing it from option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am developing a jquery plugin. What I want to do is want to check keyCode inside the plugin without passing it via the option parameter. The code is shown below.

It is not easy to explain the problem so hopefully the code will help.

**My html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lang="EN"
dir="ltr">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>Auto_complete</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.myplugin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/connect.js"></SCRIPT>


        <input name="Input" type="text" id="tags" size="55"  class="reverie" placeholder="Type Here" title="Type Here"/><br /><br /><br />
        <input name="Input" type="text" id="tags1" size="55"  class="reverie" placeholder="Type Here" title="Type Here"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**my jquery.myplugin.js**

```
(function($) {

$.fn.mymethod = function(options) {  

    var settings = $.extend({

        // These are the defaults

        name : "undefined",
        //i have some other fields

    }, options);

         return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                //here i want to check whether SPACE has been pressed or not 
                //then only alert will take place
                alert(settings.name);

              });   // this.each ends here

};         

})(jQuery);
```

**My connection.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('.reverie').mymethod({

        name : "XYZ",
       //other fields

    });
});
```

Now if I change my connection.js and jquery.myplugin.js as below then I can achieve my objective

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.reverie').keyup(function(e) {
        $(this).mymethod({
            keyCode : e.keyCode,
            name : "XYZ"
        });
    });
});
```

**jquery.myplugin.js**

```
(function($) {

$.fn.mymethod = function(options) {  

    var settings = $.extend({

        // These are the defaults

        name : "undefined",
        //i have some other fields

    }, options);

         return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if(settings.keyCode==32)
                {
                alert(settings.name);
                }

              });   // this.each ends here

};         
})(jQuery);
```

But I do not want to change my connection.js i.e. I do not want to write `$('.reverie').keyup(function(e) {` and  `keyCode : e.keyCode,` inside my `connection.js` but still want to check if the keyCode is 32, or not, inside the plug-in.

I want to know is it possible to do in this manner? If Possible then how to implement this?

If anyone has any difficulty understanding the problem I will try to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*if* I understand you correctly, you simply want to process the `keyup` event to see if `space` is pressed on *any element attached to your plugin*.

That should just mean you need to attach a `keyup` handler to each element inside the initialization of your plugin.

e.g.:

```
     return this.each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         // Connect a keyup handler to the element
         $this.keyup(function (evt) {
             // if the keycode is "space"
             if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
                 // alert will take place
                 alert(settings.name);
             }
         });
     });
```